# Error on try insert a embed of Gist (GitHub) with PHP

Tags: php, github, embed, gist

I'm trying to insert a embed of Gist with PHP as follows:

```
<?php
    echo "<script src='https://gist.github.com/schacon/4277.js'></script>";
?>
```

However, on look to console, as follows error is returned:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write
>   into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless
>   it is explicitly opened.

I've tried also:

```
echo "<iframe src='https://gist.github.com/schacon/4277.js'></iframe>";
```

and:

```
echo "<embed src='https://gist.github.com/schacon/4277.js'></embed>";
```

However both returned:

> Refused to display 'https://gist.github.com/schacon/4277.js' in a
>   frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'deny'.

How can I do to show him the gist? Or is not this way?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 1):

If the page you are accessing has the `header` `X-Frame-Options` set to `deny` you cannot access them inside an `i-frame`.

> The page cannot be displayed in a frame, regardless of the site attempting to do so.

[Check Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/X-Frame-Options)